# Mysterious "using_filesort" in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is my MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ank` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `skr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sxx` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sxx` (`sxx`,`skr`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ank`
--

INSERT INTO `ank` (`id`, `uid`, `skr`, `sxx`) VALUES
(1, 34846, 1443865873, 1),
(2, 34847, 1443777739, 1),
(3, 34848, 1443777741, 2),
(4, 34849, 1443777743, 3),
(5, 34850, 1443777745, 0),
(6, 34851, 1443777747, 0);
```

This simple query is OK:

```
explain SELECT id, skr FROM ank force index (sxx) where sxx='1' order by skr DESC limit 0, 30;

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ank   | ref  | sxx           | sxx  | 1       | const |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

but when I use where `sxx IN (1, 2, 3)` instead of `sxx='1'`, it always uses filesort. I tried everyhing - to include end exclude order by column in SQl statement, to include all columns, to not include all columns, tried order by primary column, but always the same result: `using_filesort.`

```
explain SELECT id, skr FROM ank force index (sxx) where sxx IN (1, 2, 3) order by skr DESC limit 0, 30;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ank   | range | sxx           | sxx  | 1       | NULL |    3 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

But the strangest thing is that if I join the same table with GROUP_CONCAT, `using_filesort` disappears.

```
explain SELECT n.id, n.skr, GROUP_CONCAT(f.uid) fll
    -> FROM ank n
    -> force index (sxx)
    -> left join ank f on n.uid=f.uid
    -> where
    -> n.sxx IN (1, 2, 3)
    -> order by n.skr DESC limit 0, 30;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | n     | range | sxx           | sxx  | 1       | NULL |    3 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ALL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

I don't need to join the same table in this query.Is there another way how to avoid `using_filesort` when I use `where sxx IN (1, 2, 3)`?

Comment: Try changing `SELECT @@sort_buffer_size` and then `SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * x;` where X in number of MB to higher value you got now. If it helps add it to conf file `[mysqld]
sort_buffer_size = 4M`

Comment: Why are you bothered with "using_filesort"? What problem does it create for you?

Comment: The table contains more than 800 000 rows. I think it's a problem.

Comment: So what if it contains 800k rows? The explain tells you how many rows were inspected. Why do you think using_filesort is a problem? You're solving a nonexistent problem driven by opinion and not facts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`using filesort` is not as bad as it sounds. It means that MySQL is satisfying your query by gathering rows into a temporary data structure prior to sorting them. When you use

```
  where sxx='1' order by skr DESC
```

your entire query can be satisfied using your index on `(sxx,skr)`. Why? the query engine jumps to the right place in the index. First it jumps to the part of the index containing values `1` of sxx. Then it jumps to the highest value of skr in that part of the index. Then it traverses the index row by row, downward in value. Shazam: your result set appears, already in the correct order. Your `order by` clause is satisfied by the inherent order of the index.

MySQL can't exploit the index like that if you give this clause

```
  where sxx IN ('1','2','3') order by skr DESC
```

or even this one

```
 where sxx BETWEEN '1' AND '3' order by skr DESC
```

Instead, it must (1) gather up the correct rows and (2) sort them. That's what the query planner means when it says `using filesort`. Now, if it also said `using temporary`, that would mean the gathered rows were too big for RAM and the sort was happening on your hard drive. *That* will cause performance problems.

Read this, and don't worry about `using filesort` unless you're having big performance trouble. https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/